# Calling a function defined in an existing add-in using Script Lab

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel, scriptlab

I can call custom functions inside cells that are part of an add-in which I installed using the Office Add-ins dialog.

I know I can call built-in Excel functions using the Context object. However, I don't think I can use the same method to call custom functions which came with an add-in.

If it was possible to just trigger the functions inside a cell, like when you go that cell and press "Enter", that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Excel.Range.calculate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#calculate--) to trigger the custom function in the target cell/range.